# Formula for negative binomial regression

Tags: regression, negative-binomial-distribution

I would like to list the mathematical formula of a negative binomial regression for my paper. Unfortunately I have no real knowledge of statistics or higher mathematics. I would like to use nonlinear regression to calculate the innovation output (measured by number of patents) in Stata, so far I have only found the following formula of a similar paper:

E[patents | Xit] = λit = exp (βXit-1 + εit + νi).

Here, β represents the coefficient and Xit-1 embodies time-variant firm attributes. Furthermore, νi and εit are expressing independent random variables.

a) I would appreciate if someone could explain to me what each of the subsections mean?
b) How would I adjust this formula ? My regression provides patent output as dependent variable, Independent variable: venture capital investment + several control variables and fixed time and industry effects. Does this formula keep its validity?
c) How would the formula change if a moderator is added?

Comment: To what does "subsection" refer?  Could you elaborate on what "adjustment" might be needed to this completely general formula?

Comment: The subsection refers to what the individual elements mean e.g. νi and εit = independent random variables. For me, this was written in a very general way and I don't know what the meaning behind it is.                                                 
                                                                                                                                
With adjustments was meant, whether due to the variables, which I mentioned in point b) any form of adjustment would be necessary or whether the formula, as it stands there, would be valid for my variables.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a reference to the source of your formula. A negative binomial model isn't usually termed a "nonlinear regression" but rather a "generalized linear model" that associates outcomes with a linear predictor of the form $X\beta$ via a "link function." In that context, it's not clear what $\nu$  or $\epsilon$ refer to in your equation without reference to the paper from which you got it.